# Remove element vector java

Tags: java, vector

I have 2 vectors with elements like :

```
vect 1 = [111111 5, 111111 5, 222222 5, 333333 5, 111111 2]
vect 2 = [111111 5, 222222 4, 333333 2, 111111 2, 444444 8, 333333 5, 111111 1, 222222 5]
```

How can I do in Java to remove elements of the vector 1 present in the vect 2 ?

I want get this result :

```
vect 2 = [222222 4, 333333 2, 444444 8, 111111 1]
```

Thank

Comment: Please add a little more detail. What are your vectors? Arrays, `Vector`s, `List`s?

Comment: Hi, sorry .. It is a Vector like `Vector<String> monVectorTemp = new Vector<String>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `removeAll(Collection<?> c)` of `Collection`. This is applicable to any `Collection`.

So you can do the following:

```
List v1 = ....
List v2 = ....
v2.removeAll(v1); // Now v2 contains only elements of original v2 not present in v1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collToRemoveFrom.removeAll(collection)`;

Answer (score 1):

Try removeAll method of Vector,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector v1 = new Vector();
    Vector v2 = new Vector();

    v1.add(1111);
    v2.add(1111);
    v2.add(2222);

    v2.removeAll(v1);
    System.out.println(v2);

}
```